# Access denied for javaee-web-api-8.0.1.jar

Tags: java, maven, jersey

Access denied for javaee-web-api-8.0.1.jar

javac -cp OneDrive/jersey-client-2.29.1.jar;OneDrive/javaee-web-api-8.0.1.jar OneDrive/Hello.java

error: no source files

bash: OneDrive/javaee-web-api-8.0.1.jar: Access Denied

same for commons-logging-1.2.jar/httpclient-4.5.10.jar

I tried installing javaee-web-api with maven

I tried sudo

```
javac -cp OneDrive/jersey-client-2.29.1.jar;OneDrive/javaee-web-api-8.0.1.jar OneDrive/Hello.java
```

Comment: Please show the results of `ls -l OneDrive`

Comment: no, i am still messing with it

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand what you mean by that comment.

Comment: You appear to be on Unix. **On Unix the classpath separator is colon** (:); it is only semicolon (;) on windows (because Windows already uses colon for drive:\path\file)